# How to make a new empty form using Play boot forms? (Java)

Tags: play-bootstrap

Using Play and the play-bootstrap plugin, how does one make an empty to show on a page?

That is, if I have a data object `Something`, how do I make an empty form for it using play-bootstrap, so that user's can make a new `Something`?

(Consider a Comment, say, instead of a `Something` - not to edit, to create).

Comment: Original message in this post contained this message: `I just wish people always made clear documentation - I'll answer this asap, this is just a placeholder`. OK, I'll hold off putting on hold for now, but remember that self-answered questions must still be of the same quality as "real" ones. This one is rather on the thin side... can you expand it at all? What problem did you have before you solved it?

Comment: @halfer - whoops! I forgot to answer this!

Comment: OK, thanks. Notwithstanding, if you can expand on the original question, that would still be good.

Comment: @halfer oh! i completely misunderstood your comment. yeh, is this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller class, for whichever method is loading the page you want to see (and this is using Java)

```
public Result methodName(){
    Form<Something> aForm = formFactory.form(Something.class);
    return ok(twirlFile.render(aForm));
}
```

Where `twirlFile` is the `twirlFile.scala.html` template you want to use.

Within *that* you need some code that looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" ></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" >
            @b3.form(routes.Controller.saveSomething) {
                @b3.text( form("name"), '_label -> "Title", 'placeholder -> "Enter Something name here" )
                @b3.text( form("description"), '_label -> "Description", 'placeholder -> "Enter short description here" )
                @b3.submit('class -> "btn btn-default"){ <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Save }
                @flash.get("success") 
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ></div>
    </div>
```

As a bonus, if you didn't have any empty form, and wanted to put a hidden id in your form (representing the `id` field in `Something), add in:

```
@b3.hidden( "id", form("somethingId").value, 'attr -> false
```

So your form would then look like:

```
@b3.form(routes.Controller.saveSomething) {
    @b3.hidden( "id", form("id").value, 'attr -> false
    @b3.text( form("name"), '_label -> "Title", 'placeholder -> "Enter Something name here" )
    @b3.text( form("description"), '_label -> "Description", 'placeholder -> "Enter short description here" )
    @b3.submit('class -> "btn btn-default"){ <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Save }
    @flash.get("success") 
}
```